# get longlistselector item at a particular index

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

In my WP8 app i have a longlistselector which includes CheckBox in its itemtemplate.

I want to set the IsChecked property of each checkbox in my list at run-time.

For doing this i figured i would need to loop through the items in the list and get access to the checkbox instance in each item and set its property.

But i cant find a way to get reference to a list item at a particular index in the longlistselector.

Can someone please guide me with this?? i am pretty new to this platfom.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be binding the IsChecked property to a Boolean in your ViewModel code, which you can then toggle easily by iterating through the ItemsSource list and setting to false.

Comment: @pantaloons thanks for the suggestion...i will try it out n get back to you.